# Create object from class name in JavasScript ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want create object factory using ES6 but old-style syntax doesn't work with new.

I have next code:

```
export class Column {}
export class Sequence {}
export class Checkbox {}

export class ColumnFactory {
    constructor() {
        this.specColumn = {
            __default: 'Column',
            __sequence: 'Sequence',
            __checkbox: 'Checkbox'
        };
    }

    create(name) {
        let className = this.specColumn[name] ? this.specColumn[name] : this.specColumn['__default'];
        return new window[className](name); // this line throw error
    }
}

let factory = new ColumnFactory();
let column = factory.create('userName');
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: FYI, the manually coded ES5 version of this works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4x45gqLt/.  Probably worth looking at what babeljs produces to see what is different.  Apparently `Column` is not global (and thus not on the `window` object), but the generated ES5 code would show you for sure.

Comment: Um, `window[className]` never worked reliably.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't put class names on that object. Put the classes themselves there, so that you don't have to rely on them being global and accessible (in browsers) through `window`.

Btw, there's no good reason to make this factory a class, you would probably only instantiate it once (singleton). Just make it an object:

```
export class Column {}
export class Sequence {}
export class Checkbox {}

export const columnFactory = {
    specColumn: {
        __default: Column,    // <--
        __sequence: Sequence, // <--
        __checkbox: Checkbox  // <--
    },
    create(name, ...args) {
        let cls = this.specColumn[name] || this.specColumn.__default;
        return new cls(...args);
    }
};
```

Comment: actually great factory example, used it in my project :)

Answer (score 15):

There is a small & dirty way to do that:

```
function createClassByName(name,...a) {
    var c = eval(name);
    return new c(...a);
}
```

You can now create a class like that:

```
let c = createClassByName( 'Person', x, y );
```

Comment: i like this eval solution

Comment: +1 from me too. I know everyone condemns eval but as long as you have full control of the possible values it is the simplest and most flexible solution.

Comment: i like this eval, but now any have problem, can't create variable using eval in es6 class method

Comment: i think there is a security risk of using eval()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#:~:text=eval()%20is%20a%20function,eval()%20evaluates%20the%20statements.

Comment: eval is awesome

Comment: getting "ReferenceError: Person is not defined." How do I tell eval where to look for the class?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the classes are not properties of the window object. You can have an object with properties "pointing" to your classes instead:

```
class Column {}
class Sequence {}
class Checkbox {}
let classes = {
  Column,
  Sequence,
  Checkbox 
}

class ColumnFactory {
    constructor() {
        this.specColumn = {
            __default: 'Column',
            __sequence: 'Sequence',
            __checkbox: 'Checkbox'
        };
    }

    create(name) {
        let className = this.specColumn[name] ? this.specColumn[name] : this.specColumn['__default'];
        return new classes[className](name); // this line no longer throw error
    }
}

let factory = new ColumnFactory();
let column = factory.create('userName');

export {ColumnFactory, Column, Sequence, Checkbox};
```

Comment: Is the `Column` constructor not a global?

Comment: Apparently not in babeljs (Can't post repl, too long)

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that are not using ES6 and want to know how you can create classes by using a string here is what I have done to get this to work.

```
"use strict";

class Person {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
window.classes = {};
window.classes.Person = Person;

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(new window.classes["Person"](1, 2));
```

As you can see the easiest way to do this is to add the class to an object.

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zxg7dsng/1/

Here is an example project that uses this approach:
https://github.com/pdxjohnny/dist-rts-client-web

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this method:

allThemClasses.js

```
export class A {}
export class B {}
export class C {}
```

script.js

```
import * as Classes from './allThemClasses';

const a = new Classes['A'];
const b = new Classes['B'];
const c = new Classes['C'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but recently I've had the same question about how to instance a class dynamically

I'm using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) so following the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import) there is a way to load a module dynamically using the ***import()*** function

***js/classes/MyClass.js***

```
class MyClass {
    test = null;
    constructor(param) {
        console.log(param)
        this.test = param;
    }
}
```

***js/app.js***

```
var p = "example";
var className = "MyClass";

import('./classes/'+className).then(function(mod) {
    let myClass = new mod[className](p);
    console.log(myClass);
}, function(failMsg) {
    console.error("Fail to load class"+className);
    console.error(failMsg);
});
```

***Beware:* this method is asynchronous and I can't really tell the performance cost for it**,
But it works perfectly on my simple program (worth a try ^^)

***Ps*:** To be fare I'm new to Es6 (a couple of days) I'm more a C++ / PHP / Java developer.

I hope this helps anyone that come across this question and that is it not a bad practice ^^".

Answer (score 2):

**Clarification**
There are similar questions to this, including this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655616/create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-es6-with-a-dynamic-name) that was closed, that are looking for proxy classes or factory functions in JavaScript; also called dynamic classes. This answer is a modern solution in case you landed on this answer looking for any of those things.

**Answer / Solution**
As of 2022 I think there is a more elegant solution for use in the browser. I made a class called `Classes` that self-registers the property `Class` (uppercase C) on the window; code below examples.

Now you can have classes that you want to be able to reference dynamically register themselves globally:

```js
// Make a class:
class Handler {
    handleIt() {
        // Handling it...
    }
}

// Have it register itself globally:
Class.add(Handler);

// OR if you want to be a little more clear:
window.Class.add(Handler);
```

Then later on in your code all you need is the name of the class you would like to get its original reference:

```js
// Get class
const handler = Class.get('Handler');

// Instantiate class for use
const muscleMan = new (handler)();
```

Or, even easier, just instantiate it right away:

```js
// Directly instantiate class for use
const muscleMan = Class.new('Handler', ...args);
```

**Code**
You can see the [latest code on my gist](https://gist.github.com/blizzardengle/41b45971f262508e4ae4f1fdf3a30bac). Add this script before all other scripts and all of your classes will  be able to register with it.

```js
/**
 * Adds a global constant class that ES6 classes can register themselves with.
 * This is useful for referencing dynamically named classes and instances
 * where you may need to instantiate different extended classes.
 *
 * NOTE: This script should be called as soon as possible, preferably before all
 * other scripts on a page.
 *
 * @class Classes
 */
class Classes {

    #classes = {};

    constructor() {
        /**
         * JavaScript Class' natively return themselves, we can take advantage
         * of this to prevent duplicate setup calls from overwriting the global
         * reference to this class.
         *
         * We need to do this since we are explicitly trying to keep a global
         * reference on window. If we did not do this a developer could accidentally
         * assign to window.Class again overwriting any classes previously registered.
         */
        if (window.Class) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-constructor-return
            return window.Class;
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-constructor-return
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Add a class to the global constant.
     *
     * @method
     * @param {Class} ref The class to add.
     * @return {boolean} True if ths class was successfully registered.
     */
    add(ref) {
        if (typeof ref !== 'function') {
            return false;
        }
        this.#classes[ref.prototype.constructor.name] = ref;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a class exists by name.
     *
     * @method
     * @param {string} name The name of the class you would like to check.
     * @return {boolean} True if this class exists, false otherwise.
     */
    exists(name) {
        if (this.#classes[name]) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a class by name.
     *
     * @method
     * @param {string} name The name of the class you would like to retrieve.
     * @return {Class|undefined} The class asked for or undefined if it was not found.
     */
    get(name) {
        return this.#classes[name];
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate a new instance of a class by reference or name.
     *
     * @method
     * @param {Class|name} name A reference to the class or the classes name.
     * @param  {...any} args Any arguments to pass to the classes constructor.
     * @returns A new instance of the class otherwise an error is thrown.
     * @throws {ReferenceError} If the class is not defined.
     */
    new(name, ...args) {
        // In case the dev passed the actual class reference.
        if (typeof name === 'function') {
            // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
            return new (name)(...args);
        }
        if (this.exists(name)) {
            return new (this.#classes[name])(...args);
        }
        throw new ReferenceError(`${name} is not defined`);
    }

    /**
     * An alias for the add method.
     *
     * @method
     * @alias Classes.add
     */
    register(ref) {
        return this.add(ref);
    }

}

/**
 * Insure that Classes is available in the global scope as Class so other classes
 * that wish to take advantage of Classes can rely on it being present.
 *
 * NOTE: This does not violate https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp
 */
const Class = new Classes();
window.Class = Class;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! But in my case, to have it working I had to add `export { Class}; ` in **classes.js** and import it in the **"main-file"** (the one that is called in the script-tag of the browser). Did I mess up something else to need this?

Comment: Hi @nhaggen, my code examples assumed you would be using `script` tags in the head to load your JS. You used import/export which is totally fine; you didn't mess anything up. The changes you made are correct if you use import/exports in you project.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but we can find three main approaches that are very clever and useful:

### 1. The Ugly

We can use `eval` to instantiate our class like this:

```js
class Column {
  constructor(c) {
    this.c = c
    console.log(`Column with ${this.c}`);
  }
}

function instantiator(name, ...params) {
  const c = eval(name)
  return new c(...params)
}

const name = 'Column';
const column = instantiator(name, 'box')
console.log({column})
```

However, `eval` has a big caveat, if we don't sanitize and don't add some layers of security, then we will have a big security whole that can be expose.

### 2. The Good

If we know the class names that we will use, then we can create a lookup table like this:

```js
class Column {
  constructor(c) {
    console.log(`Column with ${c}`)
  }
}

class Sequence {
  constructor(a, b) {
    console.log(`Sequence with ${a} and ${b}`)
  }
}

class Checkbox {
  constructor(c) {
    console.log(`Checkbox with ${c}`)
  }
}

// construct dict object that contains our mapping between strings and classes    
const classMap = new Map([
  ['Column', Column],
  ['Sequence', Sequence],
  ['Checkbox', Checkbox],
])

function instantiator(name, ...p) {
  return new(classMap.get(name))(...p)
}

// make a class from a string
let object = instantiator('Column', 'box')
object = instantiator('Sequence', 'box', 'index')
object = instantiator('Checkbox', 'box')
```

### 3. The Pattern

Finally, we can just create a `Factory` class that will safety handle the allowed classes and throw an error if it can load it.

```js
class Column {
  constructor(c) {
    console.log(`Column with ${c}`)
  }
}

class Sequence {
  constructor(a, b) {
    console.log(`Sequence with ${a} and ${b}`)
  }
}

class Checkbox {
  constructor(c) {
    console.log(`Checkbox with ${c}`)
  }
}

class ClassFactory {
  static class(name) {
    switch (name) {
      case 'Column':
        return Column
      case 'Sequence':
        return Sequence
      case 'Checkbox':
        return Checkbox
      default:
        throw new Error(`Could not instantiate ${name}`);
    }
  }

  static create(name, ...p) {
    return new(ClassFactory.class(name))(...p)
  }
}

// make a class from a string
let object
object = ClassFactory.create('Column', 'box')
object = ClassFactory.create('Sequence', 'box', 'index')
object = ClassFactory.create('Checkbox', 'box')
```

I recommend **The Good** method. It is is clean and safe. Also, it should be better than using `global` or `window` object:

- `class` definitions in ES6 are not automatically put on the `global` object like they would with other top level variable declarations (JavaScript trying to avoid adding more junk on top of prior design mistakes).
- Therefore we will not pollute the `global` object because we are using a local `classMap` object to lookup the required `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this easy to implement on TypeScript. Let's have an existing Test class with existing testMethod. You can initiate your class dynamically with string variables.

```
class Test {
     constructor()
     {
     }
     testMethod() 
     { 
     }
   }

    // Class name and method strings 
    let myClassName = "Test";
    let myMethodName = "testMethod";

    let myDynamicClass = eval(myClassName);

    // Initiate your class dynamically
    let myClass = new myDynamicClass();

    // Call your method dynamically
    myClass[myMethod]();
```