# Create an instance of a class in ES6 with a dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to instantiate a particular ES6 class by passing a string variable to a function. Depending on the value of the variable, a different class will be created.

*Example* - I have 2 classes, `ClassOne`, `ClassTwo`. I want to be able to pass a variable to a function and get a new class back. The name of the class will be related to the variable - eg. passing `'Two'` will create `ClassTwo`.

I **don't** want to just use a `switch` clause like this:

```
function createRelevantClass( desiredSubclassName )
{
  let args = [],
      newClass;

  switch( desiredSubclassName )
  {
    case 'One' :
      newClass = new ClassOne(args);
      break;
    case 'Two' :
      newClass = new ClassTwo(args);
      break;
  }

  return newClass;
}
```

Instead, I want to somehow be able to create the constructor call using the variable name. Is that possible?

```
function createRelevantClass( desiredSubclassName )
{
  // desiredSubclassName would be string 'One' or 'Two'

  // how to use the 'new' operator or Reflect here to create the class based on the variable passed in
  let newClass = ( *magic code to build constructor dynamically* );

  return newClass;
}
```

Comment: I could not add an answer here because this is closed, but anyone looking for a modern (2022+) solution look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71624436/3193156

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this...

## 1. Proxy Class

Following from @thefourtheye's example of maintaining a mapping of name to class, you could have a class whose job is to take the name of the desired class and proxy its instantiation:

[ [See it working](https://jsoverson.github.io/es6repl/#__v2:class%20ClassOne%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hi%20from%20ClassOne%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20class%20ClassTwo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hi%20from%20ClassTwo%20%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20class%20DynamicClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20(className)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09const%20classes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09ClassOne%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ClassTwo%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20classes%5BclassName%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20new%20DynamicClass('ClassOne')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20DynamicClass('ClassTwo')%3B) ]

**Define your classes**

```
// ClassOne.js
export class ClassOne {
    constructor () {
        console.log("Hi from ClassOne");
    }
}

// ClassTwo.js
export class ClassTwo {
    constructor (msg) {
        console.log(`${msg} from ClassTwo`);
    }
}
```

**Define the proxy class** (e.g. `DynamicClass`)

```
import ClassOne from './ClassOne';
import ClassTwo from './ClassTwo';

// Use ES6 Object Literal Property Value Shorthand to maintain a map
// where the keys share the same names as the classes themselves
const classes = {
    ClassOne,
    ClassTwo
};

class DynamicClass {
    constructor (className, opts) {
        return new classes[className](opts);
    }
}

export default DynamicClass;
```

**Example usage**

```
import DynamicClass from './DynamicClass';

new DynamicClass('ClassOne'); //=> "Hi from ClassOne"
new DynamicClass('ClassTwo', 'Bye'); //=> "Bye from ClassTwo"
```

## 2. Factory Function

Use a function that performs a lookup against an object of class name -> class mappings and returns reference to the class, which we can then instantiate as usual.

**Define the factory function**

```
import ClassOne from './ClassOne';
import ClassTwo from './ClassTwo';

const classes = { ClassOne, ClassTwo };

export default function dynamicClass (name) {
  return classes[name];
}
```

**Example usage**

```
import dynamicClass from './dynamicClass'

const ClassOne = dynamicClass('ClassOne') // Get the ClassOne class

new ClassOne(args) // Create an instance of ClassOne
```

Comment: I like this one because I don't have to explicitly build a map of variables to classes - just having a constant with the group of classes to construct is enough. @thefourtheye's example is neat but I think this is closer to what I wanted to do.

Comment: It actually doesn't have to be a class. It can be a simple factory function. A class is kinda overkill IMHO.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yep, certainly not the only way. :-)

Comment: In the end I have combined the two - a simple factory function which uses the non-mapped constant of class references. Thanks both for your great help.

Comment: I do not agree with this approach. The return value shouldn't be a class, however should be an object of the requested class from the Factory.
Please review the following link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: This is not very handy if you have a library with many classes, and the number and name of classes changes on time to time. Every update you'd have to add the new classes' name to the proxy.

Answer (score 40):

Store the classes in an Object, with the keys being the names of the classes you want them to be.

```
const classesMapping = {
  'One': ClassOne,
  'Two': ClassTwo
};
```

then create the class based on the key name like this

```
return new classesMapping[desiredSubclassName](args);
```

Comment: Out of interest, would the classes have to be defined in the same module as `classesMapping`?

Comment: @RGraham Nope. Not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it through and makes sense that it would as modules would have to be imported at some stage, e.g. https://plnkr.co/edit/luvxe81sIHQSwIyGwBdC?p=preview

Comment: @RGraham Oh, that site looks nice :-) Thanks :-)

Comment: This is one of the coolest things I've seen. Thanks. The added trouble of making a mapping pays off immensely, I think.

Comment: Eye opening .. Thanks ! But what if the desiredSubclassName were actually the same as the class name already ? Mapping 'ClassOne' into ClassOne seems a bit redundant to me. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @bertie If you're using ES6 it is possible. There is a shortcut where { 'Foo' : Foo } could be write as { Foo }

Comment: Thanks. Probably the most elegant solution for avoiding the eval() function

Comment: If typescript, you can populate the class map using decorators automatically.