# Unable to require a class using require.context

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm looking to create an easy way for users to extend various services within a `nodejs` app. It uses `electron`, `webpack`, and `babel`.

I found a handy way to dynamically `require` every file in a given folder:

```
// At the top of my class file
const thing_files = require.context('./things', false, /\.js$/)

// In my class constructor
this.things = {};

thing_files.keys().forEach(key => {
    try {
        this.things[key.replace(/(\.\/|\.js)/g, '')] = thing_files(key).default; // edit: also tried default()
    } catch(err) {
        process.send({message:`unable to add thing ${key}`});
    }
});
```

This works great for files that look like the following:

```
export default {

    getName() {
        return 'thangythang';
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work when I export a class:

```
import Thing from "../base-thing";

export default class extends Thing {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    getName() {
        return 'thangythang';
    }
}
```

Nor with a named class:

```
export default class ThingOne extends Thing {
```

These classes otherwise work well when I `require` them as expected:

```
const ThingOne = require('./things/thing-one')
var thing = new ThingOne.default();
process.send({message:`thing: ${thing.getName()}`}); // thing: thangythang
```

How can I work with them using `webpack`'s `require.context`?

Comment: You're loading a `thing_files` context but then iterating `exchange_files`, is that a mistake?

Comment: A mistake in generic-ifying my post. I have 8 loaders that all look the same.

Comment: So if you inspect the object returned by `thing_files(key)` what do you see? Also, does it work if you comment out `import Thing from "../base-thing";` and remove `extends Thing`?

Comment: It returns `undefined` when I output it to the console. I haven't quite figured out how to inspect it since this is under a child process.

Comment: Cool. Try commenting out the stuff I mentioned, if that works I have a guess what the issue is. Also, do you mean `thing_files(key) === undefined` or `thing_files(key).default === undefined`?

Comment: `export default class ThingOne` with the `import` statement commented out still produces `undefined`. `thing_files(key)` is an `Object` while `thing_files(key).default === undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

After toying with various things, I realized that:

```
export default {}
```

Essentially assigns an `Object` to `default`, while `export default class ThingOne` does not. With that in mind, I changed my class file to the following:

```
import Thing from "../base-thing";

class ThingOne extends Thing {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    getName() {
        return 'thangythang';
    }
}


export default new ThingOne();
```

Which also worked. However, I wanted something more robust *just in case* I needed to pass parameters during construction, or create more than a single instance of the class. After [playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655616/create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-es6-with-a-dynamic-name) around [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name) alternative ways of instantiating a class, I came across a valid solution!

```
this.things[key.replace(/(\.\/|\.js)/g, '')] = new (thing_files(key).default)(/* args */);
```