# Create Javascript classes dynamically

Tags: javascript, class

I have a question which shouldn't be to difficult, but I've been spending days and can't seem to find the answer. All the solutions I found didn't help me, they all threw errors.

I made a Class in Javascript and want to create a new instance dynamically, so that I can instantiate multiple classes depending on the parameter in a function. It doesn't seem te work, and I wonder why.

settings.js and main.js are loaded via `<script>` tag in the HTML file, with settings.js being loaded first.

main.js

```
let myClass = new settings(); // Works
let myClass2 = test('settings'); // Error: Uncaught TypeError: param is not a constructor

function test(param){
  return new param();
}
```

settings.js

```
class settings{

  constructor(){
    console.log("works");
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: param is a variable, you probably are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655616/create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-es6-with-a-dynamic-name

Comment: You cant just instantiate a string, you could probably use the string to look up the class though, e.g. `new window[param]()`

Comment: Well, the error is very succinct. You're passing in 'settings' as an argument and expecting the function to return an instance of it. But it's not a constructor - it's a string.

Comment: Just remove the single quotes. `let myClass2 = test(settings);`

Comment: @csmckelvey: That would defeat the whole purpose of having a dynamic lookup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: @H.B. OP doesn't want dynamic lookup.

Comment: @H.B. what do you mean by "dynamic lookup" you can't pass a string and expect it to magically return the class that is named the same.

Comment: csmckelvey, removing the quotes worked. I'll look into the other answers aswell, thanks all!

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `console.log(42); // works` and `var x = 42; console.log('x'); // doesn't work`

Comment: @RyanSchaefer: Yes you can, if passed as a key to an object for example as noted by Marie.

Comment: I would have answered that you should implement a Factory style design pattern in JS with sample code but a question marked as "duplicate" is locked. Why am I suggesting Googling "Javascript Factory design pattern example"? Well you're trying to define a function that will return a class object depending on the variable value passed to it. If you intend to define more than one class value (e.g. "settings", "config", "action") then you'll be basically following a Factory pattern. A quick Google will reveal a bunch of good examples.