# JavaScript: can I access the object that contains imported modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I'd like to create an array of the modules I am importing into `Main.js` file. How might I access the object that contains the imported modules?

**EDIT** To further explain, I am importing multiple classes into a `Main.js` file containing a Main class. Each of these classes comes from their own individual file, giving me import statements like this:

```
import Header from './features/Header.js';
import ImageStrip from './features/ImageStrip.js';
import AreaChart from './features/AreaChart.js';
import Axes from './features/Axes.js';
```

Is there a JavaScript object that contains the modules that are imported, for example something like `[ Header, ImageStrip, AreaChart, Axes ]`? Or is it possible to create one?

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information to answer this properly. Could you expand your examples to include multiple files and exactly what you'd expect to see?

Comment: As I understand it, you want an equivalent of Node's [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut)/[`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports) object, but one containing all *imports* by the current file.

Comment: UPDATE: This approach satisfies what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no data structure that is automatically populated with the imports of the current file. You will have to construct your own array or object that manually lists each import.

```js
import Feature1 from './features/Feature1.js';
import Feature2 from './features/Feature2.js';
import {SubFeatureX} from './features/Feature3.js';

const imports = [Feature1, Feature2, {SubFeatureX}];
// or
const imports = {Feature1, Feature2, Feature3: {SubFeatureX}};
```

If you need to create this variable in every file and are worried about the effort of maintaining the lists manually, you could compile the project with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and could [write a Babel plugin](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md) to add this variable for you at the top of each file.

Answer (score 1):

`file.js`

```
export firstFunc() {}
export nextFunc() {}
```

`newFile.js`

```
import * as Obj from "./file.js";
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense in the case of having one file you are importing from. But what if I am importing modules from multiple files? Is there a JS object that contains them? Or can I push them all into the same object?

Comment: This made so much sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import {firstMethod, secondMethod} from "./firstFile";
import {anotherFirstMethod} from "./secondFile";

export {
    firstMethod,
    secondMethod,
    anotherFirstMethod
};
```

or

```
import * as Obj from "./firstFile";
import * as Obj2 from "./secondFile";

export {
    Obj,
    Obj2
};
```