# Test the existence of a dynamically chosen class

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have data coming from an external source that I want to process. In order to do that, the objects I'm receiving are tagged with their original class name. Now I want to take that tag name and use it to populate a model in my own application. I'm stuck at the step where I check for that class having an equivalent in my codebase. Its going to look something like this:

```
this.objects.forEach((object) => {

if (typeof object.class_tag !== 'undefined') { //the problem line
//create class instance
}

});
```

In php I'd simply call class_exists to achieve this

```
<?php
if (class_exists($object->class_tag)) {}
```

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: How important is the type safety in your app? For example, does it *have* to be an instance of X class? Just thinking anonymous objects would be a lot easier here.

Comment: @James there is a requirement to treat data differently on a per model basis. That would be difficult in plain objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing it

(credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34656123/746549)

```
let logger = require('../javascripts/serverlog');
let util = require('util');

let Extension = require('../models/object/Extension');

const classes = {Extension: Extension};

/**
 * Utility to emulate class exists / dynamic class naming
 * @param className
 * @returns {*}
 */
module.exports.dynamicClass = (className) => {

    logger.debug(classes);
    logger.debug(className);
    if (classes[className]) {
        return classes[className];
    } else {
        return false;
    }

};
```

Usage:

```
let ClassOrFalse = dynamicClass.dynamicClass(object._class_tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the clear way to do this in a just one line.

One of the possible approaches is the way you register your existing classes.
For example if you use some kind of a `namespace` later on you can simply check the class for existance in the namespace.
Sample code:

```
class A {}
const a = "A"
const namespace = { A };

if (namespace[a]) {
  // class exists, you can create object
  const instance = new namespace[a]();
}
```

Probably, much better approach would be to make some `service`, that will `registerClass`, `checkClass` and `createInstance` for you. So your logic is wrapped in one place.

Comment: For me, a service is the way to go here - there's no idiomatic way of doing this and I would say explicitness would be better to avoid any unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @James I would say, there is some architectural problem in the app, if TS has to do something like this.