# Instantiate class dynamically but prototype is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I tried to instantiate dynamically my class in a Vue JS with TypeScript project.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655777/7085783).

It works in Angular 2+ but in my Vue project I have this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
```

I have a Classes.ts file

```
import {CMyClass} from 'path/to/my/class';
export const Classes = {
     CMyClass: CMyClass
}
```

My class file :

```
import {CMyOtherClass} from 'path/to/my/mother/class';
export class CMyClass extends CMyOtherClass {
     constructor() {}
}
```

My mother class file :

```
export class CMyOtherClass {
    constructor() {}
}
```

And my function to instantiate a class :

```
import {Classes} from 'path/to/Classes/constante';
buildClass(className: string): any {
     return new Classes[className]();
}
```

An idea ?

Comment: `Classes.ts` should maybe be `export const Classes = {` (With an `=`) since you're exporting an object?

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen I don't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: In `Classes.ts` you have `export const Classes { ... }` which is exporting an undefined constant `Classes`, and then creating an unnamed object `{ CMyClass: CMyClass }` as a separate statement (imagine that there's a semicolon after `export const Classes`). What you want is an equals sign `=` to assign the value of the object to a new constant `Classes`, ie `export const Classes = {`. See here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgMZQHYGdEGEA2BDddEdBAb2AUsqwFkBPXA9ALgVof0OAF9g-xo8ZGkxtOREgF4yFKm3qNCrdovQ8gA

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen Oh sure, I did a mistake when I write my question. I have an "=" in my code. But It doesn't works. I edited my post.

Comment: That error sounds like `CMyOtherClass` does not have a prototype. Or which line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: @Bergi I think to, when I remove the extends it works. But I don't know I have to do to keep the parent class. Have you got an idea ?

Comment: @V.Pivet Where does `CMyOtherClass` come from? Please post the code related to it.

Comment: @Bergi I edited my post. I hope this can help.

Comment: @V.Pivet Looks normal. Any circular dependencies?

Comment: @Bergi hum no ...