# JavaScript: dynamic instance of class based on variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's suppose that a library offers different classes (lib.Class1, lib.Class2, lib.Class3, ...).
I have a variable "name" which stores the name of the class to be instantiated (Example: const name = "Class2").

How can I dynamically instantiate a class based on the variable?
For example: const myClass = new lib.name(params); (I know this doesn't work).

I don't want to build any map myself because the library can change over time and offer different classes.

Can Reflect be any useful?

I know there is this question but it is creating a "map" which I'd like to avoid: [Create an instance of a class in ES6 with a dynamic name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655616/create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-es6-with-a-dynamic-name).

Comment: Have you tried `new lib[name](params)`

Comment: Oh god, was it really that simple? *Facepalm*. Now I'm questioning my JS skills XD.

Comment: I am not sure if there is another way

Comment: "*it is creating a "map" which I'd like to avoid*" - `lib` already is such a map :-)

Comment: I once worked with a guy who didn't trust `instance.method()` so he always wrote `instance['method']()`. The two things are equivalent throughout JS.