# To what extent can I treat classes and types as objects themselves? And why does mapping an enum to a class not work?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to be able to map an enum to a class type (not an instance, but the actual classname itself), and then use this for various things. It appears to be something TypeScript supports; there's a way of doing so shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72231610/typescript-object-with-classes-as-a-values). Then, I assume, I could reference that mapping to create instances of the class (`new map['className']()`) and retrieve the types [of the properties of that class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and so on.

Unfortunately, not only does this not work, but it displays behaviour which is a bit mystifying, and indicates a fundamental lack of understanding on my part of how TypeScript handles type information.

To what extent can I do runtime reflection and type management in this way with TypeScript?

```
enum FooTypes {
  Bar = "Bar",
  Baz = "Baz"
}

module FooDataTypes {
  export class Bar implements FooData {
    readonly type: FooTypes = FooTypes.Bar;
    data: string = "default";
  }

  export class Baz implements FooData {
    readonly type: FooTypes = FooTypes.Baz;
    data: number = 100;
  }
}

abstract class FooData {
  abstract readonly type: FooTypes;
  static readonly types: { [key in FooTypes]: { new(...args: any[]): FooData } } = {
    Bar: FooDataTypes.Bar,
    Baz: FooDataTypes.Baz
  };
}

function isFooData(object: any): object is FooData {
  return 'type' in object;
}

// This is an example of the kind of thing I want to do with FooData.types,
// but shouldn't be taken as the core problem I'm trying to solve.
function populateWithDefaults(partial: any) : FooData {
  // This is example code, so I'm eliding most safety checks etc.
  if (!isFooData(partial)) {
    throw new Error("Invalid partial!");
  }

  let fd: any = new FooData.types[partial.type]();
  for (const key in partial) {
    if (key == "type") { /* Don't try and override the type, that would go down poorly. */
    } else if (!(key in fd)) {
      console.warn(`Invalid member '${key}' was culled from Foo Data instance: ${JSON.stringify(partial)}`);
    } else if ((typeof partial[key]) !== FooData.types[partial.type][key]) {
      console.warn(`Skipped member '${key}' in Foo Data instance due to invalid type; was '${typeof partial[key]}' instead of '${FooData.types[partial.type][key]}'.\nPartial: ${JSON.stringify(partial)}\nObject: ${JSON.stringify(fd)}\nClass: ${JSON.stringify(FooData.types[partial.type])}\nFooData.types: ${JSON.stringify(FooData.types)}`);
    } else {
      fd[key] = partial[key];
    }
  }
  return fd;
}
populateWithDefaults({ type: FooTypes.Bar, data: "bar" });
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nAKgTwA7AM5QN4CgpQBCAhgE5QC8UARCadQDT5HEBelNJr1uAvrrghwAJmAA2wWAgAixAC7EU6LHgLAAHqjik5UAMZjiGLHSgBLCKgkRQcrPDiyFOZgVLBiwuCDHIoctGAALikkQKwqByVMADo6AG5XKGF5YhCMOVIzEABzDmphYAAzYnE5akSCfmYNLR19Q2MWdgsrYBsQO1CnYhcCNw8vHz8A9BCo8I4J5Ti2Sv6UhRDwCAAjYHIqAEYABh35-mriVYzSYj1dAyN7GVS+qGPT8913T29ff0DxhGiMeYz5GY9FBXkMPqNMCFsFAANoAa2AfmyoV+AF0oVAQMAAO4AChiBLIOQwIWIIGQMNRAEpvo47rwoAyqKp+nRaT1frNSEx+s12alOVxmLxEtUimAQBczN5zBgHD1cXBVgArYAXUnkmlQJWqi6y7p3FnuORgUggKAAcghFvM5p1arkooEAHpnVBEAALMxYb0Pc0aYiWCTaor+D2SOHZYQhsPZPIASSg2LJujkcGS6exZjkHoNChiEIwTFdUFWYF0GA9cHEwhAVtLkgUCPNRjDkj02kkqFISusUHjFugmWQcf86YwcDEADdgDFcOLJXJpeatKhxPJgAB1bMe6TFUpiOy41BkJfEMQa5BUqD85wskue32+gNB9siYAMKAT-uDqDAMRmMIo5CBkX7EEUwABPo4Z6HCWCQXoc4EGYoa4gAhN68qpMep5mOeVLXiyBA5j22KYjiUAAKKkD2pC4tQ8YgFO56AVAJ46HhYhodQVIHAIBASLoRTCJeHBYmRWH5oWMLsWeYgFoEqK4rxzBFNoUC4h2ICgQiSIrrh+H3MhqG6ZQVDUBCPE4FAzoAFRQNI3j1sOfrRnAM40YBjbhp86Cfjm8hJtWYjRjk6ZeNiK4IKQvgxFAtnOkkDL-hgkgoRpaG4qZyLCQRRn9FpE4SDEyZmriAAGjHMQB0Y2GsGyWgAJNgum8DayZYHo4gSNGRQ9tADgOXc2QApKwRQM1ABSADKADyAByMSnHGKHIDhHH4bw5UqbyyViKl5iobiEJwKGsmcfCiLUlAaEUJEtxSeEMkGfJEKopdyDXURBXeEVs6lSAFXTZGqDoLV7TrOQFrNa1NrIoNPS2qNeiSKIjbptk1WsRC8RJq20PYCdZ0vR9qJtUjciDDGBOScQCnKM9G2vYppNtTEAA6IAAAovSEU1zYty25Kt61yVSvCc7NKoOnz2AzQtS2ZCtRRrblEsgAAwo0JITXLAuK1kwsq7itP05gjNyWb1Lq6bhay-LgtK0ba22+E4vbfMVR-vtkjfQQwmkxw53nqTnuMsKzDGqa5rCU6q7rpT245nuJRlBguLQhCtKCmQn6LGkNCrGQ1CMrxQA)

When I run this, I get:

```
[WRN]: "Skipped member 'data' in Foo Data instance due to invalid type; was 'string' instead of 'undefined'.
Partial: {"type":"Bar","data":"bar"}
Object: {"type":"Bar","data":"default"}
Class: undefined
FooData.types: {}"
```

Not only does the member-type access not work, but `FooData.types` isn't even populated.

Comment: `Bar` and `Baz` only implement the type. they don't extend or derive.

Comment: Your understanding is fine, `FooData.types` is populated, you just don't see it because of `JSON.stringify`. Classes (as well as functions which TS transpiles classes into) cannot be stringified (so `JSON.stringify(FooDataTypes.Bar) === undefined`) and by extensions any object properties that contain classes are excluded from the result (so `JSON.stringify({a: 1, bar: FooDataTypes.Bar}) === '{"a": 1}'`, and `bar` is omitted). If you do `console.log(FooData.types)` without stringifying and look into devtools console (not TS playground logs tab) you will see that it is populated as expected