# If array contains different type elements, how to pick the same type elements and create new array with it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, typeof

> Hi! So I want to get the following result:
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuWeR.png)

and here's the js function that i wrote. The problem is that the output of my function is null.

```js
function dataTypeArray(arr, type){
    for(i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++)
    var string = [];
    var number = [];
    var boolean = [];
    var i;
    if(type = 'string' && typeof arr[i] == 'string'){
        string.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
        if(type = 'number' && typeof arr[i] == 'number'){
            number.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            if(type = 'boolean' && typeof arr[i] == 'boolean'){
                boolean.push(arr[i]);
            } else { 
                return 'null';
            }}} 
        return string, number, boolean;}


var arr = ['hhg', 'fthth', 456, true];
console.log(dataTypeArray(arr, 'string'));
```

Comment: 1. This `type = 'number'` should be `type === 'number'`. `=` is assignment and `==` or `===` is comparison. 2. `return string, number, boolean;` You can return only 1 value from a function. 3. `for(i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++)` Missing braces. So body will only be next line, i.e. `var string = [];`

Comment: 4. Also, declare variables outside `for`. 5. This `return 'null';` will break the loop so you do not need this

Comment: @Terra ... From all the provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var arr = ['hhg', 'fthth', 456, true];
var strings = arr.filter(x => typeof x === 'string');
var numbers = arr.filter(x => typeof x === 'number');
var booleans = arr.filter(x => typeof x === 'boolean');
```

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh has already listed in their comment what is going wrong in your current code. I'd recommend you to move to modern JavaScript, the task becomes quite easy:

```js
function getTypeMap(arr) {
  const typeMap = {};
  for (const val of arr) {
    const key = `${typeof val}s`;
    typeMap[key]?.push(val) ?? (typeMap[key] = [val]);
  }
  return typeMap;
}

const exampleArr = [0, 'a', 1, 'b', true, 2, false],
  {booleans, numbers, strings} = getTypeMap(exampleArr);

console.log(booleans, numbers, strings);
```

As said, you can't return multiple values from a function. Here we create an object with keys by types of the values in the array, and return the object. In the loop, the code checks whether a property named by the type of the value exists using [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`s` is added at the end of the type because you can't create variables named `function` and `undefined`). If the operator returns `undefined` we'll create a new array with the current value in the first index (see [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)), otherwise we just push a new value to the type array.

Properties from the returned object are then assigned to variables using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (`{booleans, numbers, strings} = ...`). This way you can get any array of the types, just pick those you need when destructuring the returned object to the variables, or store the returned object to a variable, and use its properties where needed.

If you need more accurate type than `typeof` operator can return, you can do something like at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hjLyubd/1/).

Answer (score 0):

One possible generic approach could be based on [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and this method's 2nd [`initialValue` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#syntax) which will be passed to (and continued being passed around by) the reducer function.

This reducer is implemented around the initially passed object which features both a `result` object where the final result gets aggregated and a `detection` property which is a fully customizable key value based configuration of type detection functions.

Thus one implements the reducer once and then configures its usage at will.

```js
function detectAndCollectType({ detection, result }, type) {
  const isAnyMatch = Object

    .entries(detection)
    .some(([ key, isType ]) => {
      const doesMatch = isType(type);
      if (doesMatch) {

        (result[key] ??= []).push(type);
      }
      return doesMatch;
    });

  if (!isAnyMatch) {
    (result.unhandled ??= []).push(type);
  }
  return { detection, result };
}

// 1st usage example.
const { result } = [null, void 0, 0, 'a', 1, 'b', true, 2, false, new Date]
  .reduce(detectAndCollectType, {
    detection: {
      boolean: val => 'boolean' === typeof val,
      number: val => 'number' === typeof val,
      string: val => 'string' === typeof val,
    },
    result: {},
  });

console.log({ result });

// 2nd usage example.
const { result: {

  nullish,
  boolean,
  number,
  string,
  date,
  
}} = [null, void 0, 0, 'a', 1, 'b', true, 2, false, new Date]

  .reduce(detectAndCollectType, {
    detection: {
      nullish: val => (val ?? null) === null,
      boolean: val => 'boolean' === typeof val,
      number: val => 'number' === typeof val,
      string: val => 'string' === typeof val,
      date: val => '[object Date]' === Object.prototype.toString.call(val),
    },
    result: {},
  });

console.log({
  nullish,
  boolean,
  number,
  string,
  date,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit** ... in order to reflect the discussion with **@Teemu***

As it has been discussed in the comments below, there is another generic `reduce` based approach which is more strict in terms of type detection due to its straightforward implementation which extracts a type's (internal) class name and collects any array item accordingly.

Here everything depends on a proper type detection which is a very specific field on its own.

```js
// helper function for exposing a value's (internal) class name.
function getClassName(value) {
  const regXClassName =
    // ... [https://regex101.com/r/flUvPh/1]
    (/class\s+(?<customName>[^\s{]+)(?:\s+extends\s+\S+)?\s*\{|function\s+(?<builtInName>[^\s(]+)\s*\(/);

  let customName, builtInName;
  if ((value ?? null) !== null) {

    ({ customName, builtInName } = regXClassName
      .exec(String(Object.getPrototypeOf(value).constructor)).groups ?? {});
  }
  return customName || builtInName || (/\[object\s+(?<className>[^\]]+)\]/)
    .exec(Object.prototype.toString.call(value))
    ?.groups.className;
}
// the above helper is part of the following SO answer
// ... [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421732/how-to-know-what-class-inheritance-is-object-from-database/73775470#73775470]


function detectAndCollectTypeByItsClassName(result, type) {
  const key = getClassName(type)
    // first character to lower case.
    .replace(/./, match => match.toLowerCase());

  (result[key] ??= []).push(type);

  return result;
}


console.log(
  ['hhg', 'fthth', 456, true]
    .reduce(detectAndCollectTypeByItsClassName, {})
);
class CustomDate extends Date {}

console.log(
  [null, void 0, 0, 'a', 1, 'b', true, 2, null, false, new Date, new CustomDate]
    .reduce(detectAndCollectTypeByItsClassName, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: A less verbose way to use `reduce` would be `return arr.reduce((a, v, {t = typeof v}) => (a[t]?.push(v) ?? (a[t] = [v]), a), {});` = ).

Comment: @Teemu ... The above chosen design on purpose is open to more than just a `typeof` operator based type detection where the latter does neither support `null` values nor object types other than just `'object'`. The approach's introducing explanation and both code examples do emphasize this too.

Comment: In the injected argument [you can use a function call](https://jsfiddle.net/0u9o8exh/) instead of `typeof` operator.

Comment: @Teemu ... but then one can not use any type detection function which targets a very specific condition and always returns a boolean value like e.g. `isUndefinedOrNull` (nullish).

Comment: No? Please add some null or undefined values to `exampleArr` in the fiddle code, and test. Hmm ... For nullish values we need to remove lowercase, and use capitalized "class" names instead.

Comment: @Teemu ... I don't need to. I can read it from the fiddle code. One could not collect undefined and null values into one and the same `nullish` values array. One also could not separate Number objects from number types.

Comment: Why to collect them to the same array, they're not the same of type? It's also easy to add such a line to the code. Capitalization of the variable names will shadow many of the global constructors, though.

Comment: @Teemu ... Thats why I wrote ... _"possible generic approach"_. Your linked fiddle code is **generic _but strict_**. The above presented solution is **generic _and customizable_** and exactly like I wanted it to be. Otherwise I would have written something like your fiddle code. Why not **making the fiddle part of _your answer_** otherwise it might get overlooked.