# JavaScript: Where are classes stored? (How are they accesible via a string containing the class name?)

Tags: javascript, class

The title says it all. The only thing I can find is that global variables are stored under *window* but that doesn't seem to be true for classes defined using the *class* keyword.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
   console.log('A Foo is created');
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const bar = new window['Foo'](); // TypeError: window.Foo is not a constructor
```

I know one can write something like `let Foo = class Foo {}` but I would like to keep the redundancy low. Also, I'm interested if a true, non-work-around solution exists just out of curiosity.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of that, that doesn't deal with classes.

Comment: The solutions proposed in the possible duplicate don't work for me. Neither `window['Foo']` nor `this['Foo]`. November 2016, Firefox 49.0.2.

Comment: See also [Do `let` statements create properties on the global object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572) - you'd need to use `var` not `const` or `let`. For your actual use case, see [Create object from string in JavasScript ECMAScript 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31776949/1048572)