# Javascript class from string variable name

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic

I have a class name and want to use it to create a class instance dynamically. How can I do that?

```js
class FieldText {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hello text field');
  }
}

class FieldTextarea {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hello textarea field');
  }
}

function callField(name) {
  new FieldText(); // Somehow use name variable instead to make it dynamic
  // new Field${name}(); // Does not work
}

callField('text');
```

Comment: Put the classes in an object and refer to that? `globalThis.FieldTextarea = FieldTextarea` which allows `globalThis['FieldTextarea']`

Comment: `const elements = { Text: fieldText; Textarea: FieldTextarea };` and then you can do `new elements[name]`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060784/14032355

Answer (score -1):

```js
class FieldText {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hello text field');
  }
}

class FieldTextarea {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hello textarea field');
  }
}

this.FieldText = FieldText;
this.FieldTextarea = FieldTextarea;

function callField(name) {
  return new this[`Field${name}`];
}

callField('Text');
```