Javascript: Any way to create a class by constructing class name using strings/variables dynamically without eval?
I've tried myriads of ways to create new class instances dynamically, without using eval and hard coded key-value pairs, to no avail. Seemingly there is no way in modern Javascript to query the user defined classes and/or to create them. Is there any remedy to my problem?
Example:
class Whatever {}
class Anything {}
classes = {Whatever, Anything}

//These ofc doesn't work 
instance = new ['Whatever']()
instance = new window['Whatever']()

//This works, but eval...
x = eval('Whatever')
instance = new x()

//This also works, but with mapping, not nice

new window['classes']['Whatever']()


What is wrong with new classes["Whatever"]()?

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042459/how-to-instantiate-a-class-from-a-string-in-javascript

If there was a way to get objects from names easily, then the input must be absolutely secured, otherwise you have an injection vulnerability. If the class chosen is in any way based on user controlled input, then a user could instantiate any class, which may be Really Not Good™. It's a good thing you have to at least provide a "whitelist" of potential classes via classes = {Whatever, ...}.

@deceze Wow... who asked for this?

@MalackaPower Didn't you?

@Bergi I asked for a solution, not some lecture on security. Those reward points went into your heads big time.

@MalackaPower It is still not clear what the actual problem is you are trying to solve and what your constraints are. If you don't care about security, just use eval - or do you have some other reasons to avoid it? Why are you trying to avoid the classes dictionary (or are you even)? The solutions shown in the duplicates use the most straightforward approach, we cannot suggest alternatives if you are not specific about why those approaches don't work for you.
