# Javascript new operator help needed - dynamic object using the new operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I was looking to get an idea working but I can't seem to figure it out.  I would like like to do something like the following.

```
// my old fasion code but not very flexibale 
function runCode() {
  var x = new myObject();
  return x.run();
}
```

What I really like to be able to do.....

```
// pass in string paramater of object to create
// objName is the name of an object string to new like "myObject"
function runCode(objNameToUse) {
  var x = new Object(objNameToUse);
  return x.run();
}
runCode("myObject");
```

How could I do something like this using javascript?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: `Object` generally refers to the global `window.Object`. Better to use a different variable name, or you will easily cause confusion

Comment: @CertainPerformance There is no such thing as the Global `window.Object`. `Object` is the most fundamental object type in JavaScript, but that has nothing to do with Global or `window`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `Object === window.Object` -> `true`? Hrm, I don't know, actually, if referencing `Object` would work without `window` or some other global having that property

Comment: I stand corrected, in part. The BOM doesn't define an `Object`, JavaScript does. `window.Object` simply points to that. In other words, `Object` is a native member of ECMAScript, not `window`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: JavaScript defines it to be on the global object, which is `window` for browsers. Anyway, was just disambiguating the name in the comment.

Comment: @Ry- The Global object is only `window` in a browser. It isn't in, say Node.js. That's why it's important to distinguish where its definition lies.

Comment: basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/how-do-i-make-javascript-object-using-a-variable-string-to-define-the-class-name 

If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create object from string in JavasScript ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776949/create-object-from-string-in-javasscript-ecmascript-6)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a mapping from names of available constructors to the constructors themselves, like with an object:

```
var someConstructors = Object.create(null);
someConstructors.myObject = myObject;
…

function runCode(objNameToUse) {
  var constructor = someConstructors[objNameToUse];
  var x = new constructor();
  return x.run();
}

runCode("myObject");
```

`Object.create(null)` is an object that doesn’t inherit the properties of `Object.prototype`, so you don’t have unexpected extra “keys”, like `hasOwnProperty`. Important because the usual reason to do this is if you wanted to create objects based on a string outside of your control (e.g. user input); in many other cases, you could just pass `myObject` directly to `runCode` as a function instead of a name.

So, make sure this isn’t actually what you’re looking for for “flexibility”:

```
function runCode(constructor) {
  var x = new constructor();
  x.run();
}

runCode(myObject);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're **absolutely sure** that you 100% control which class name is passed to your function at any time, you can use `eval`:

```js
class myObject {
  run() {
    console.log('run');
  }
}

function runCode(objNameToUse) {
  var x = new (eval(objNameToUse))();
  return x.run();
}

runCode('myObject');
```

Comment: You know I thought about the eval.  I am always told eval is evil but I thought it would work for my case.  However, this environment I am working in has disallowed eval.  I was able to test on my personal machine and yes eval would work just can't use it for my needs.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's to be avoided 99% of the time but if you're entirely in control of what you pass over to it then in some very rare occurrences it can be practical, and I thought that was one of these cases. Guess whoever downvoted disagreed :) Anyway, I'll leave the answer in case it can help future visitors, I feel like the warning is clear enough as it is.

Comment: Just found it's a dupe of [Create object from string in JavasScript ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776949/create-object-from-string-in-javasscript-ecmascript-6), so I just voted to close the question. I like how one of the solutions suggests `eval` and is upvoted there, btw.