# ES6: How to use a variable classname?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
let className = 'Person';
return new [className](data);
```

However this gives the following error:

```
TypeError: "[...] is not a constructor"
```

I have defined the class using the class keyword, as follows:

```
class Person extends Entity {...}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create object from string in JavasScript ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776949/create-object-from-string-in-javasscript-ecmascript-6)