# React: Array.reduce + Object.assign for dynamic hookrouter routes complains re: PascalCase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, reduce, assign

I'm trying to set routes in hookrouter dynamically.  Current routes are an array of four objects which are mapped into `li`s:

```
const routes = [
        { href: '/', label: 'Root' },
        { href: '/About', label: 'About' },
        { href: '/Sites', label: 'Sites' },
        { href: '/Blog', label: 'Blog' }
    ].map(route => {
        route.key = `nav-route-${route.href}-${route.label}`;
        return route;
    });

// End result I need:
// export const directions = {
//  '/': () => <Root />,
//  '/About': () => <About />,
//  '/Sites': () => <Sites />,
//  '/Blog': () => <Blog />
// };

// This solution comes very close, but complains of PascalCase:
export const directions = routes.reduce(
    (object, Item) =>
        Object.assign(object, { [Item.href]: () => <Item.label /> }),
    {});


const NavList = props => {
    return (
        <NavContainer>
            <ul>
                {routes.map(({ key, href, label }) => (
                    <A href={href} key={key} className='route-link'>
                        <li className={href === window.location.pathname ? 'active' : null}>
                            {label}
                        </li>
                    </A>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </NavContainer>
    );
};

export default NavList;
```

Update: So I originally submitted this question when I was having issues putting functions into an object, but  `Object.assign()` inserts functions into the empty object without issue.

Now the problem I'm having is React complaining about PascalCase.  Here's the exact error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: <About /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

But the routes array has labels with capitalized letters.  I tried capitalizing 'I' in `Item` for the `Object.assign()` method, which interestingly React accepts the first route and errors on the second route if the I is capitalized.

Comment: Where do the components come from, and what are their actual names?

Comment: // route objects in array, keys are 'href' and 'label':
const routes = [
        { href: '/', label: 'Root' },
        { href: '/About', label: 'About' },
        { href: '/Sites', label: 'Sites' },
        { href: '/Blog', label: 'Blog' }
    ]; 

// Array.reduce extracts objects, Object.assign maps values to new object with arrow functions and components as values:
const directions = routes.reduce(
    (object, Item) =>
        Object.assign(object, { [Item.href]: () => <Item.label /> }),
    {});

Comment: That's the code you already posted. I meant where are you defining the components like `<Root />` and `<About />`?

Comment: They're defined in separate files.  They're imported at the top (omitted).  They work properly with the `directions` object written by hand (the commented-out portion). The `Array.reduce(Object.assign())` code appears to make an object just like `directions`, but React complaints about it - either because it's being generated dynamically, or there's something just slightly different about it I'm not seeing in console.log.

Comment: "*They're imported at the top (omitted).*" - ah, now we're talking. The problem is that `Item.label` is a string, not a reference to the imported component. You need to pass the component itself. You could use an object or `Map` to look it up by your label, though.

Comment: Ohhh... I didn't think of that.  Thanks for sticking with me - would you mind answering w/ an example and I'll try it out?

Comment: I've already closed it as a duplicate :-) Maybe also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31776949/1048572) for how to access the classes dynamically.