# Create class constructor using eval: getting ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, eval, es6-class

I'm trying to create class constructor dynamically and came acrosss the following solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40069309/1713920

```
//TeamMemberProfile.js
export default class TeamMemberProfile{
}

//helpers.js
function createClassByName(name,...a) {
    var c = eval(name);
    return new c(...a);
}
```

But when I try to use it:

```
//somewhere in project
let obj = createClassByName("TeamMemberProfile")
```

It throws `ReferenceError: TeamMemberProfile is not defined` which isn't a surprise.

However, what should I do in order for `eval` to understand that code?

DISCLAIMER: whether it's a good or bad idea to use eval is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: You'd need to import `TeamMemberProfile` into `helpers.js` module so that `createClassByName` has visibility of it

Comment: @NickParsons thanks. Tried that, still the same. Even added console.log right before eval like this: console.log("name = ", name, ", TeamMemberProfile = ", TeamMemberProfile) and "name" prints "TeamMemberProfile" string, while the second parameter prints the class correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: do you use any bundlers? (Webpack, rollup, parcel, etc?)

Comment: @OlegWock, yep, webpack+bable. I guess I'm out of luck?

Comment: if you add your classes to global scope (`window.TeamMemberProfile  = TeamMemberProfile`) after import your code should work. If that isn't an option, then I'm afraid it will either require a lot of custom configuration for webpack or impossible altogether

Comment: Although your approach with creating instances by class name is uncommon in JavaScript. You might want to modify it a bit to have a hashmap of name -> constuctor and lookup by name in this hashmap, instead of using eval. Results (and amount of code) should be same, but there won't be eval (which might have security implications) and in future you'll be able to use TypeScript if you decide to do so

Comment: @OlegWock thanks. Ok I got you. Manual map is exactly what I'm trying to get rid of, but having that I'll have to declare all classes anyway for eval to work, that doesn't make much difference. Now I'm thinking of possible ways to scan all the codebase to find all the classes and to build that map programmatically.

Comment: @OlegWock you are saying that in TypeScript those type of things are pretty straightforward, right?

Comment: No, I say that if you decide to move your project to TypeScript, solution with hashmap will be easier to type properly than solution with eval. Solutions themself doesn't change, as TypeScript is merely extension of JS, not a fully separate language